# Set devise mailer locale with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, delayed-job

I'm sending my devise emails asynchronously by setting the following method on the model

`def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
        devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
     end`

My problem is that since delayed_job spans a new process to send the mails, it can't inherit the locale used by the requester and ends falling back to `:en` regardless if the user was using it or not.

I tried enveloping the method body with `I18n.with_locale` but it didn't work:

`def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
     I18n.with_locale(:"pt-BR") do
        devise_mailer.send(notification, self, *args).deliver_later
       end
     end`

Taking into consideration that the locales are set based on the request url top level (e.g. .co.uk sets `I18n.locale` to `:en` and .com.br to `:"pt-BR"`), anyone has an idea of how to make it send the mails with the correct locale?